# onclick cant pass value to child

Tags: reactjs

I have a function in my parent file (schedules) called edit, and I want to be able to pass the usageMode state from the edit function to the dataRows file. However state only seems to work in the schedules file and I have tried passing props into the setUsageMode. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Schedules.js

```
const schedules = () => {

  const autoComplete = useContext(AutoCompleteContext)
  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)

  const [scheduleData, setScheduleData] = useState([])
  const [showScheduleModal, setShowScheduleModal] = useState(false)
  const [usageMode, setUsageMode] = useState('Read')

  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadScheduleData(){
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const [results, projectResults] = await Promise.all([
        get('get_testing_schedules', user.user),
        get('get_projects_autocomplete/t', user.user)
      ])
      autoComplete.setProjectsAutoComplete(projectResults)
      setScheduleData(results.data)
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }
    onLoadScheduleData()
  }, [])

  const sortedScheduleData = [].concat(scheduleData)
    .sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1)

  const showModal = () => setShowScheduleModal(true)
  const onCloseScheduleModal = () => setShowScheduleModal(false)

  const edit = () => {
    setUsageMode('Edit')
    console.log(usageMode);
  }

  return (!scheduleData ? null :
    <PageWrapper title='Schedules'>

      <div style={{marginBottom: '20px'}}>
        <Button
          onClick={showModal}
          className='Button Dark Main'
          text='CREATE SCHEDULE'
        />
      </div>

      <div className='Card'>
        <div className='TableTopbar ScheduleGrid'>
          <div>ID</div>
          <div>Interval</div>
          <div>Project ID</div>
          <div>Database</div>
          <div>Create Timestamp</div>
          <div>Create User Id</div>
          <div>Edit</div>
        </div>

        {sortedScheduleData.map(schedule =>
          <ScheduleDataRow
            key={schedule.id}
            schedule={schedule}
            setScheduleData={setScheduleData}
            edit={edit}
            usageMode={usageMode}
          />
        )}
      </div>

      <ScheduleModal
        setScheduleData={setScheduleData}
        setShowScheduleModal={setShowScheduleModal}
        showScheduleModal={showScheduleModal}
        onCloseScheduleModal={onCloseScheduleModal}
      />
    </PageWrapper>
  )
}

export default schedules
```

DataRows.js

```
const scheduleDataRow = props => {

  const autoComplete = useContext(AutoCompleteContext)
  const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)

  const [usageMode, setUsageMode] = useState(props.usageMode)
  const [scheduleFieldData, setScheduleFieldData] = useState({})

  console.log(usageMode);
  const onEditScheduleClick = () => {

    setScheduleFieldData({
      'id': props.schedule.id.toString(),
      'interval': props.schedule.interval,
      'project_id': props.schedule.project_id,
      'database': props.schedule.database,
      'create_timestamp': props.schedule.create_timestamp,
      'create_user_id': props.schedule.create_user_id
    })
    setUsageMode('Edit')
  }


  const onCancelEditScheduleClick = () => setUsageMode('Read')

  const onScheduleFieldUpdate = (e, valueFromAutoComplete, nameFromAutoComplete) => {
    const name = nameFromAutoComplete ? nameFromAutoComplete
    : e.target.name || e.target.getAttribute('name')
    const value = valueFromAutoComplete ?  valueFromAutoComplete.map(val => val.value).join(',')
    : e.target.innerText ? e.target.innerText
    : e.target.value

    setScheduleFieldData({...scheduleFieldData, ...{[name]: value}})
  }

  const onSubmitEditClick = async () => {
    loading.setLoading(true)
    const results = await verifiedPost('post_testing_schedule', scheduleFieldData, user.user)
    if (results.status === 0) {
      setUsageMode('Read')
      props.setScheduleData(results.data)
    } else if(results.status >= 20 && results.status <= 30) {
      user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
    }
    snackbar.statusCheck(results)
    loading.setLoading(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className='Table ScheduleGrid'>

      {usageMode === 'Read' ?
        <React.Fragment>
          <div>{props.schedule.id}</div>
          <div>{props.schedule.interval}</div>
          <div>{props.schedule.project_id}</div>
          <div>{props.schedule.database}</div>
          <div>{props.schedule.create_timestamp}</div>
          <div>{props.schedule.create_user_id}</div>
          <div>
            <EditIcon
              style={{padding: '2px', width: '0.8em', height: '0.8em', marginRight: '5px'}}
              className='CircleButton'
              onClick={props.edit}
            />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>

        :

        <React.Fragment>
          {configs.map((config, k) => {
            const Field = config.field
            return (
              <div key={k} className='Main'>
                <Field
                  uniqueIdentifier={k}
                  placeholder={config.label}
                  name={config.name}
                  onChange={onScheduleFieldUpdate}
                  onSelect={onScheduleFieldUpdate}
                  onAutoCompleteOnChange={autoComplete.onProjectAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
                  options={config.name === 'interval' ? config.options : autoComplete.projectsAutoComplete}
                  value={scheduleFieldData[config.name]}
                  initialValues={config.name !== 'project_id' ? []
                  : scheduleFieldData['project_id'].split(',').filter(x => x).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
                }
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}

          <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
            <div>
              <Button
                style={{marginRight: '10px'}}
                text='Submit'
                className='Button Dark Main'
                onClick={onSubmitEditClick}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Button
                text='Cancel'
                className='Button Dark Main'
                onClick={onCancelEditScheduleClick}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

scheduleDataRow.propTypes = {
  schedule: PropTypes.object,
  setScheduleData: PropTypes.func
}

export default scheduleDataRow
```

Comment: setUsageMode is async, so the console.log in the edit function will happen before the value has been set.

Comment: so it should be setting it fine then?

Comment: I think your problem here is that you have 2 usageMode states, and you are getting mixed up between them. edit() sets the usageMode in your parent file but in the child file you are still trying to use the local usageMode value. If you change `usageMode === 'Read'` to `props.usageMode === 'Read'` do you get what you want?

Answer (score 0):

in scheduleDataRow.js

const [usageMode, setUsageMode] = useState(props.usageMode)
this code actually means, take a snapshot of props.usageMode, use it as an initial state of the scheduleDataRow.

so usageMode in parent and child is completelty different.

you should use usageMode directly, not create a new state in scheduleDataRow.